# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I foreach ViewBag object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I am trying to understand why I get an exception when I try to get elements from a string array containing roles for my application.

> error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   (ViewBag.roles)

Here is how I am getting the roles:

```
   public ActionResult AdminRolesAndAccessRules()
   {
        String[] rolesArray;
        rolesArray = Roles.GetAllRoles();

        ViewBag.roles = rolesArray;

        return PartialView();
    }
```

and here is how I am using the information:

```
<div class="scroller">
    <table>
        @foreach (MembershipUserCollection muc in ViewBag.roles)
    {                                        
        if(column == 1) {
            classe = "whiteRow";
            column = 0;
        }
        else {
            classe = "grayRow";
            column = 1;
        }
    <tr class="@classe"> 
        <td class="adminSetFormRowUsuario">role</td> 
        <td class="adminSetFormRowGrupo"></td> 
        <td class="formAction centerAlign">
            <img src="~/Images/editar.gif" alt="Editar"/>
            <span style="margin-left:5px"></span>
            <a href='javascript:AjaxRemoveUser("/Account/DeleteUser?role=@muc", "POST", "DinamicContent", "AdminSettingsTabsStructure")'><img src="~/Images/excluir.gif" alt="Excluir"/></a>
        </td> 
    </tr>

    }     
    </table>
```

Debugging I can see 2 values in `ViewBag.roles` but still the system complaining about a Null or not instantiated object.

Comment: It looks like you are assigning an array of strings to ViewBag.Roles, but then iterating through those strings as a different type (`MembershipUserCollection`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// string array being assigned here
String[] rolesArray = Roles.GetAllRoles();
ViewBag.roles = rolesArray;
```

> Debbugging I can see 2 values in ViewBag.rules but still the system
>   complaining about a Null or not instatiated object.

Those 2 values are presumably the roles you assigned.

```
// This looks wrong...you are treating each string in the array as MembershipUserCollection
@foreach (MembershipUserCollection muc in ViewBag.roles)
{
}

// instead, this should give you the role names
@foreach( string role in ViewBag.roles )
{
    <div>@role</div>
}
```

Comment: I tried that too in the first time. Did´nt work either! I have also changed the controller to string[] not String[].

Comment: Have you tried just writing out the role names verbatim (I just updated my example)?

Comment: yes.. <td class="adminSetFormRowUsuario">@role</td>. The exception happens when the code gets right on top of ViewBag.roles inside of the foreach. It does not get inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I am really ashamed for my mistake. I am using a jquery tab structure where I load different views and this particular one was bein contructed before the object was created thus a null reference. Problem solved